# How to convert udp mpeg ts stream to http stream?

Tags: http, ffmpeg, udp

I'm trying to stream a live video on a website and I already have a **udp mpeg-ts**. I cannot show this stream on html so I wanna **convert** this stream to **http** on server then send it to clients. how can I do that using **ffmpeg**?
any other solution accepted too.
thank you

Comment: There are many examples of using ffmpeg to create hls or dash streams on stackoverflow, and other websites.

Answer (score 1):

The key question is - do you need a low latency live streaming or 15-30 seconds latency is OK for you. If you don't need low latency, use ffmpeg to ingest your udp mpeg-ts and output HLS.
For low latency live streaming to web browsers, you will have to install a media server software, such as Wowza / Unreal Media Server / Red5 or similar.
The media server will ingest your udp mpeg-ts and will convert it to WebRTC streams playable by web browsers.